# how can i create histogram of vector<vector<long>>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have allocated `vector<vector<long>>`. what is the right way to create histogram or use std::find over all vectors without relocation of  the data ?

thanks

Comment: you are creating a 2D array of `long`, you want to know how to iterate over all the elements of your matrix?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you want to do and what you have tried.

Comment: the number of vectors are determined & allocated at run time. once this is done i what to have histogram (count of each val). I tried to append all vectors and sort .. ugly ........... must be better way

Comment: @BenRendel , Are you looking for the count of each value of the vector? If you're structure contained the following data, for example, `{ {1,2,3}, {1,5,3}, {2,1,7} }` are you looking for something that would report `1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1`?

Comment: yes. in your example there are 3 short vectors. in my application there are hundreds of vectors and they are much longer

Answer (score 1):

By histogram I understand a map value->occurrences, and with your data this means a `map<int, int>` and I do not understand how std::find kicks in. Said this I would go for something like this:

```
// assuming exists vector<vector<long<long>>
std::map<long, int> histogram ;
for (const auto &v1 : vect)
    for (auto value : v1)
    {
        auto it = histogram.find(value) ;
        if (it == histogram.end())
             histogram[value] = 1 ;
        else
            it->second++ ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, what you need is a way to gather all the values in the vectors you are collecting at runtime and keep track of how many of each there are. Luckily there are several standard algorithms and containers that can handle this task efficiently.

```
std::unordered_map<long,unsigned int> histogram;
std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&histogram=histogram](std::vector<long>& inner_vec)
     {
          for(long val : inner_vec)
          {
            ++histogram[val];   
          }
     });
```

You did mention that the amount of vectors you're dealing with could be large. This problem could quit easily lend itself to a multithreaded solution.

An initial attempt may be to have each thread have its own `std::unordered_map<long,unsigned int>` and track the count for a subset of the larger dataset,then merge the results back into a larger `histogram` whenever all the threads finish.

Here's a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07f3fadf365c7059) demonstrating each of the methods described above. You should compile all of these with optimization settings to truly get a sense as to how fast this can work out for you and measure to see if the multithreaded solution even offers benefit.

Comment: thanks you for your reply. your solution is a nested loop total of N vectors x K elements, how about merging+sorting than have one loop ? Even better having "super iterator" (addressing all vectors to eliminate merge & sort)

Comment: @Ben Rendel , Maybe I'm not understand it very well, but I don't see how the sorting part would be of too much benefit. I have a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7393c899e951a87c) here demonstrating what I mentioned in my answer about the multithreading approach. It seems to be that expanding the vector  as you would like, degrades the performance. Check it out!

Comment: @BenRendel , Here's [another demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07f3fadf365c7059) that compares the 3 approaches

Comment: i really appreciate your detailed reply

Comment: Great! I hope it helped. Let me know if there's anything else you want to discuss

Comment: @BenRendel, did any of the answers given solve your problem?